# Compare a HashSet<string> with an array of strings in LINQ?

Tags: c#, string, csv, linq, hashset

I have a List called LabelFilter. Label has a Name field which is just a string such as "Test1" or "Test2" ect. I can easily convert this list into an Array of type string or a long string. The only thing that is important is the string not the IDs.

I have an IQueryable results which is the dataset I am filtering. Each Log contains a field called Label which could be anything from the following "Test2 , " or "Test2 , Test3, Test1, " or NULL or "Test3 , Test1, ".

I want to return only the records which has at least one matching string.

E.g if LabelFilter contains the Labels "Test1" and "Test3" then results with Labels that equal "Test2 , Test3, Test1, " and "Test3 , Test1, " should be returned.

I was getting a CS0854 - An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments` error when I used:

`results = results.Where(result => result.Label != null && result.Label.Split(',').Where(x => sb.ToString().Contains(x))));`

I have since tried a few different ways but I'm still not getting my expected result :(

This is also what I have tried:

```
if (LabelFilter != null && LabelFilter.Count > 0)
    {
        var labelArray = new HashSet<string>(LabelFilter.Select(s => s.Name)); // labelArray[0] = "Onhold" 


        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            if ( item.Label != null)
            {
                var t = item.Label.Split(",", System.StringSplitOptions.None); // t[0] = "Onhold" / t[1] = "Test" / t[2] = "test4" / t[3] = "" 

                var s = item.Label.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries); // s[0] = "Onhold" / s[1] = "Test" / s[2] = "test4" / s[3] = ""

                // Currently using
                var u = item.Label.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // u[0] = "Onhold" / u[1] = "Test" / u[2] = "test4" 

                var v = item.Label.Split(',').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)); // IEnumerable v[0] = "Onhold" / v[1] = "Test" / v[2] = "test4" 
            }             
        }


        results = results.Where(r => r.Label != null && r.Label.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Any(l => labelArray.Contains(l)));
}
```

Comment: Does your project have LinqKit?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly passing the default value of the optional 2nd parameter of `string.Split()`? Try: `result.Label.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None)`.